# Remix does not show openzeppelin counter variable in Debugger

Tags: remix, contract-debugging, dapp-debugging, local-variables

[image]

My local `x` variable is appearing in the debugger, why is the `game_id` variable not showing up?

Answer (score 1):

I think its because it was Private State Variable